# Validation Password and updating the dictionary Python

Tags: python, passwords, banking

I have to create a validation function to check if my password meets all the requirements:

The password must be at least 8 characters.
- The password must contain at least one lowercase character.
- The password must contain at least one uppercase character.
- The password must contain at least one number.
-The username & password cannot be the same

```
def valid(password, username):
    isValid = True

    if len(password) < 8:

        isValid = False
        return isValid
    elif password == username :
        isValid = False
        return isValid
    elif not any(x.islower() for x in password):
        isValid = False
        return isValid
    elif not any(x.isupper() for x in password):
        isValid = False
        return isValid
    elif not any(x.isdigit() for x in password):
        isValid = False
        return isValid
    elif isValid:

        return isValid
username = "Brendon"
password = "ui67SAjjj"
print(valid(password, username))
```

Then I have to write my signup function, and check if my username is in my user_accounts(dictionary). If it is not, I have to:
- Updates the username and the corresponding password in the user_accounts dictionary.
- Updates the log_in dictionary, setting the value to False.
- Returns True.

```
def signup(user_accounts, log_in, username, password):
    if username not in user_accounts.keys():
        return True
            
    
        if valid(password)== password:
            
                
            user_accounts[username] = password
            log_in[username]== False
            return True
        
        else:
            return False
            
                
    else:
        return False
```

When I run the code, I get this:

```
{}
{}
True
```

My dictionary is empty, I think my dictionary.update command is wrong, because the validation function is working.
These two functions are link to another one in which I open a file.txt. Thank you for your help

Comment: what do you have in user_accounts.  is it only one object or array of user credentials objects?

Comment: You have `if valid(password)== password:
            
                
            user_accounts[username] = password
            log_in[username]== False
            return True
        
        else:
            return False
` part of code after return statement, which never reaches.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following function. May be this is what you required

```
def valid(password, username):
    if len(password) < 8:
        return False
    elif password == username :
        return False
    elif not any(x.islower() for x in password):
        return False
    elif not any(x.isupper() for x in password):
        return False
    elif not any(x.isdigit() for x in password):
        return False
    else:
        return True




def signup(user_accounts, log_in, username, password):
    # username not there, so unable to signup
    if username not in user_accounts.keys():
        return False
    else:
        # If password is not valid, return False
        if valid(password):    
            # If both username exists and password is valid, you can check if user credentials are valid and continue 
            user_accounts[username] = password
            log_in[username]== False
            return True        
        else:
            return False
```